# Tinymce textarea not loading when file path is set dynamically using Servlet Session or Servlet Request

Tags: jsp, attributes, tinymce

I have created a JSP file and embeded Tinymce editor in it. I am trying to dynamically load Tinymce editor text area with the html file using the file path retrieved from servlet session attribute or servlet request attribute. But the textarea is not loading when I am trying to get the file path from the servlet session/request attribute. 
On the contrary if I hardcode the file path in jsp, the text area gets loaded with the html file content.
I am using following code snippet for realizing my requirement:

```
    var htmlfile=<%=(String)session.getAttribute("htmlfile")%>;
var relativepath = "../";
var html = relativepath.concat(htmlfile);
alert(html);
$.get(html,function(response) { 
    alert("xxx") ;
    tinyMCE.activeEditor.setContent(response);
});
```

But it didn't work.
On the contrary, if I check following, it works:

```
    var htmlfile="file1019318009999821318.html";
var relativepath = "../";
var html = relativepath.concat(htmlfile);
alert(html);
$.get(html,function(response) { 
    alert("xxx") ;
    tinyMCE.activeEditor.setContent(response);
});
```

In the first case, even alerts are not working.

Comment: Can you put edit code to use code format? It will help a great deal with readability

Comment: I have formatted the code and hope it's readable now.

Comment: I just tried `tinyMCE.activeEditor.setContent(response);` on my project and it's working perfect . you should check backend code if it have any responsing first  .